# Custom Django Model Form Field that Aggregates Multiple Instances of an Input

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a custom field in a model form that I want to use to enable users to enter multiple instances of inputs into. For example, the custom field is a series of values that corresponds to multiple dates. Once the form is submitted I want to consolidate all of those values into a string and store them in a single database field. See code below. The cleaned_data fields are empty when I add multiple values to the inputs. I think I need to access the input data before it is passed to cleaned_data, but I'm not sure how. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
#forms.py
class UpdateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    custom_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Model

    def clean_custom_field(self):
        custom_field = self.cleaned_data['custom_field']
        return custom_field



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #I've tried to access the input fields here without success


#views.py    
class ModelView(UpdateView):
model = Model
form_class = UpdateModelForm
template_name = 'model_edit.html'


def form_valid(self, form):
    #not sure what to put here


#model_edit.py
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Amount</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for i in '12345'|make_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{form.custom_field}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data between the data is passed to the form, you can override the `POST` method of the `ModelView`. I assume you've tried to override the `def form_valid`, but this method is called right after successful form validation (already after cleaning the data, before save).

You should be able to access the data in the `POST` request directly by overriding `def post(request, *args, **kwargs)` method on the `ModelView`.

Another possible solution would be overriding `__init__` method of the form as you've already tried. The way to accomplish this is by putting you code that modifies the data before `super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)` is called.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # ! <-- BEFORE super()
        # Here should be the form data accessible in the **kwargs dict.
        # by modifying data in the kwargs and later passing them to the 
        # super() you can alter the data before cleaning it in form.

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ! <-- AFTER super() [not here] I've tried to access the input fields here without success
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @kryštof-Řeháček. Your response put me on the right track. I was able to accomplish my objective by updating the post method (changing the **init** was not working). See code below:

```
#views.py    
class ModelView(UpdateView):
    model = Model
    form_class = UpdateModelForm
    template_name = 'model_edit.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        data = dict(request.POST.lists())
        custom_field = str(data['custom_field'])
        request.POST['processed_custom_field'] = custom_field
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```